# Display images from web url in multi threading

Tags: multithreading, blackberry

I have 52 images that is coming from web URL.I want to display this images in multi threading process.

Can any one guide me how it is possible?????

I implement below code but its not working.

```
    for (int i = 0; i <total_data; i++) {

        GetBitmapClass getBitmapClass=new GetBitmapClass(i, image_path[i]);

        if(Thread.activeCount()>14)
        {
            //System.out.println("Size "+pending_thread.size());
            pending_thread.addElement(getBitmapClass);

        }else
        {

            getBitmapClass.start();
        }

}


        //Thread class




        class GetBitmapClass extends Thread
        {
            int index;
            String url;

            public GetBitmapClass(int index,String url)
            {
                this.index=index;
                this.url=url;

            }

            public void run() {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                StreamConnection stream = null;
                InputStream in = null;


                if(Thread.activeCount()>14)
                {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }




                System.out.println("Thread "+index+" Started \n count= "+Thread.activeCount());

                try {
                    //stream = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(url+";deviceside=true;");
                    stream = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(url+";interface=wifi");
                    in = stream.openInputStream();
                } 
                catch (Exception e) {

                }

                byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                try {
                    DataBuffer db = new DataBuffer();
                    int chunk = 0;
                    while (-1 != (chunk = in.read(data))) {
                        db.write(data, 0, chunk);
                    }
                    in.close();

                    data = db.getArray();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                EncodedImage jpegPic = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(data, 0,
                        data.length);
                        Bitmap bm = jpegPic.getBitmap();

                        bmp[index]=bm;


                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater (new Runnable() {
                        public void run() 
                        {   

                            bitmapFields[index].setBitmap(bmp[index]);
                            gridFieldManager.add(bitmapFields[index]);

                            if((pending_thread.size()>0))
                                {
                                    GetBitmapClass thread1=(GetBitmapClass)pending_thread.elementAt(0);
                                    try
                                    {
                                        thread1.start();
                                        pending_thread.removeElementAt(0);
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e) {
                                        // TODO: handle exception
                                        System.out.print("Thread Not Started");
                                    }

                                    System.out.println("Size Reduce"+pending_thread.size());
                                }
                            System.out.print("Thread Completed"+index);
                        }
                    });

        }
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is happening here.. it seems like it should work. Check your firewall. and then get me proper info how it is behaving.

Comment: This code is work properly in Blackberry Simulator But In Blackberry device at most 32 images are loaded..  I dont know exactly what happening in device. So give me some suggestion.

Comment: check this could be the problem with the image size. if the image size is huge then it might give you memory issues. As a result it will throw some memory out exception. Are you getting any such exception run-time.. ??

Comment: No Neel i am not getting any kind of run time exception.

Comment: I took some time to remformat your question with proper markup for the code. I don't think you accurately posted your code segment. For example: do you really declare GetBitmapClass inside the for loop? I suggest you edit your question using proper markup (the curly braces button {} allows you to post code) and make sure you post all relevant code fragments. It looks like your code logic will never pull pending threads off of whatever structure you're using, but it is hard to tell with what is there.

Comment: Hello Richard, now i edit my question using markup. start one thread from pending thread when other thread finish its activity. I hope now you can understand my structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to close stream connection. its required to close stream connection.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to run a lot of threads at the same time is a bad idea for BB. This is not a desktop. Ususally you should avoid running more than one heavy background thread, otherwise you risk to slowdown your main UI thread to a level where users will stop using your app and call it "sluggish". Your threads are heavy - they resize images, do networking, manipulate Bitmaps. In order to fix this you need to create a list of `Runnable` tasks and execute them on the only background thread. From my experience executing tasks sequentially is more efficient on BB than trying to run them all at once.